# Unable to install a npm package and dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm trying to adapt an external API named cric-live into my node application for displaying cricket scores in my application. When I try to install the dependency, it shows an error as below

```
PS F:\Node Express\NodeJS\cric api> npm i cric-live
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"request-promise","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thiluxan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-01T04_51_42_400Z-debug.log
```

This is the source link for the dependency I'm trying to install
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cric-live?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your npm cache maybe busted so I would say run this code first and try installing the package again

```
npm cache clean --force
```